# Error : 'AddressOf' expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6-migration

I faced an error when upgrading VB6 code to VB.NET. The error occurs at 
`AddressOf WindowProc`

> *AddressOf expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type*

My declaration for `SetWindowLong` is:

```
Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32"  Alias "SetWindowLongA"(
                    ByVal hWnd As Integer, 
                    ByVal nIndex As Integer, 
                    ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
```

variables:

```
Dim GWL_WNDPROC As Short = -4  
Dim hWnd As Integer
```

Code for `WindowProc`:

```
Function WindowProc(ByVal hw As Integer, ByVal uMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim a As String
    Dim wp As Short
    Dim temp As Object
    Dim ReadBuffer(1000) As Byte
    'Debug.Print uMsg, wParam, lParam
    Select Case uMsg
        Case 1025
            Debug.Print(VB6.TabLayout(uMsg, wParam, lParam))
            Debug.Print(uMsg & "  " & wParam & "  " & lParam)

            e_err = WSAGetAsyncError(lParam)
            e_errstr = GetWSAErrorString(e_err)

            If e_err <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print("Error String returned -> " & e_err & " - " & e_errstr)
                Debug.Print("Terminating....")
                do_cancel = True
                'Exit Function
            End If
            Select Case lParam
                Case FD_READ 'lets check for data
                    x = recv(mysock, ReadBuffer(0), 1000, 0) 'try to get some
                    If x > 0 Then 'was there any?
                        'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Constant vbUnicode was not upgraded. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="55B59875-9A95-4B71-9D6A-7C294BF7139D"'
                        'default
                        'a = StrConv(System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(ReadBuffer), vbUnicode) 'yep, lets change it to stuff we can understand
                        a = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(ReadBuffer) 'yep, lets change it to stuff we can understand

                        Debug.Print(a)
                        rtncode = Val(Mid(a, 1, 3))
                        'Debug.Print "Analysing code " & rtncode & "..."
                        Select Case rtncode
                            Case 354, 250

                                Progress = Progress + 1

                                Debug.Print(">>Progress becomes " & Progress)
                            Case 220
                                Debug.Print("Recieved Greenlight")
                                Green_Light = True
                            Case 221

                                Progress = Progress + 1

                                Debug.Print(">>Progress becomes " & Progress)
                            Case 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 451, 452, 500
                                Debug.Print("There was some error at the server side")
                                Debug.Print("error code is " & rtncode)
                                do_cancel = True
                        End Select
                    End If
                Case FD_CONNECT 'did we connect?
                    mysock = wParam 'yep, we did! yayay
                    'Debug.Print WSAGetAsyncError(lParam) & "error code"
                    'Debug.Print mysock & " - Mysocket Value"

                Case FD_CLOSE 'uh oh. they closed the connection
                    Call closesocket(wp) 'so we need to close
            End Select
    End Select
    'let the msg get through to the form
    WindowProc = CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndProc, hw, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

What is the reason for the error I get? How do I solve the problem?

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? And there are multiple things wrong with the code above.

Comment: How are `lpPrevWndProc`, `hw`, `uMsg`, `wParam`, and `lParam` defined and set?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food - `hw`, `uMsg`, `wParam` and `lParam` are the parameters to the `WindowProc` function. `lpPrevWndProc` is presumably where the return value from `SetWindowLong` is being stored (but the OP hasn't, of course, shown us the actual line of code containing the erroneous attempt to use `SetWindowLong` to override the window proc)

Comment: @sozai, I've fixed the formatting of your question for you. Please make yourself familiar with the [Markdown syntax used on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before you post again! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to use P/Invoke to set the window procedure, have you looked at overriding your Form's [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) method? It may take a little more work during the re-write, but you'll end up with better code. Example from the previous link:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        ' Listen for operating system messages
        Select Case (m.Msg)
            ' The WM_ACTIVATEAPP message occurs when the application
            ' becomes the active application or becomes inactive.
        Case WM_ACTIVATEAPP

                ' The WParam value identifies what is occurring.
                appActive = (m.WParam.ToInt32() <> 0)

                ' Invalidate to get new text painted.
                Me.Invalidate()

        End Select
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
```

You might also want to look in the [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb27wehh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace for appropriate replacements for your current socket code.

---

I've also found an article [".NET Makes Window Subclassing Easy"](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/Dotnet/archives/0112/hankins/index.html), which might be useful if, for instance, you don't own the window you're trying to subclass. Any way around though, the one way that's not recommended is by trying to override the Window Proc using `SetWindowLong`